# Remove validation of invisible form fields

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

In the model, for property **ItemDescription** I have set attribute **[Required]**
Depending on my UI selections, I make this field in the view sometime visible, and sometime invisible.

How do I make unobtrusive validation to ignore **[Required]** attribute when this field is invisible.

**This is what I tried so far:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //doesn't seem to do anything. The field is still validated
        $("form").validate().settings.ignore = "#ItemDescription";

        //throws an error
        $("form").data("validation").settings.ignore = "#ItemDescription";

        //doesn't seem to do anything. The field is still validated
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: "#ItemDescription"
        });

        //doesn't seem to do anything. The field is still validated
        $("#ItemDescription").removeAttr("data-val");
        $("#ItemDescription").removeAttr("data-val-required");
 });
```

My guess is that I am making these calls too late. 
I am using jquery 1.9.0 and jquery.validate 1.9.0

Thanks

Comment: How are you hiding the value? If you render it initially using `@Html.HiddenFor()` then validation will not be performed. If however you are using jquery to hide it then its too late (the `$.validator` has already parsed the form and you would need to re-parse it)

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is. When and you hide the control, add a hiddenfield with the right name that contain the value you want (probably the default val). Or you should control the value in a hiddenField so you won't have the required issue. Dataannotation are not made to be ignored.

Do you use ViewModel ? If not it's a good idea to do so. So in the ViewModel the property won't have the Required. So on the server side you can put the value you want when converting the ViewModel into a Model to update the DB.

I hope it's clear.

Comment: I use view model. I have [Required] annotation for unobtrusive validation. I just want to ignore it when field is invisible. By reading on Google, it seems it can be done. The only thing is that I tried everything that is suggested and it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure how would adding hidden field solve the problem. Even hidden field won't have any value. Would have to do [Required] with AllowEmptyString=true... not sure...

Comment: What do you want to do with the required field empty ? If it's for saving in the DB it won't work either ... You can put a fake value and when the property contain that fake value do something you want.

Comment: In DB, the field is not required. Only in the ViewModel I specify that it is required so I can use benefits of unobtrusive validation. But, OK, I understand now what I could do... Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").validate({
    ignore:'#ItemDescription'
});
```

The `ignore` setting allows you to specify a selector which will be ignored when validating the form. In this case, I've specified the ID selector.